# How to appropriately deserialize dynamic JSON?

Tags: c#, json, ajax, json.net

I have a  service that accepts JSON, and as a part of forwarding the requests from the Browser to a web server to the service (also an HTTP Server), I have this code:

```
if (Request.HttpMethod.ToLower() == "post")
{
    var jsonObj = ObjectFromRequestBody<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    if (jsonObj != null)
    {
        // uses Newtonsoft JSON Serializer to re-serialize the object; this is RestSharp
        requestToForward.AddJsonBody(jsonObj);
    }
}
```

ObjectFromRequestBody looks like this:

```
protected T ObjectFromRequestBody<T>()
{
    Stream requestStream = Request.InputStream;
    requestStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string json = new StreamReader(requestStream).ReadToEnd();
    var payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    return payload;
}
```

Now, this works fine, assuming that it -is- a JSON object being posted. (a KVP collection)

However, I imagine in the case that the payload is simply a value (int, string, boolean, or heck, even an array), this will error out.

I've tried simply deserializing to a type of Object results in it being re-serialized into an array of empty arrays; probably because Newtonsoft's JSON Serializer by default deserializes Objects to JObjects, which is essentially an enumerable of KVPs.

Is there a type agnostic way to get from Object to serializing to the appropriate type without essentially writing a series of conditional statements?

Answer (score 0):

In this case a much better solution is to simply pipe the request body directly into the RestSharp request.

```
if (Request.HttpMethod.ToLower() == "post")
{
    var requestBody = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestBody))
    {

        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter("", requestBody, RestSharp.ParameterType.RequestBody);
    }
}
```

Though, would still be interested in hearing how to type-agnostically serialize a JObject properly.